# Let $f(x)=1-x-x^3$Find all real values of $x$ satisfying the inequality,$1-f(x)-f^3(x)>f(1-5x)$

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)=1-x-x^3$Find all real values of $x$ satisfying the inequality,$1-f(x)-f^3(x)>f(1-5x)$

---

$f'(x)=-1-3x^2$,so $f(x)$ is a decreasing function.But i do not know how to solve this inequality.
The answer given in my book is $(-2,0)\bigcup (2,\infty.)$

Comment: Is $f^3(x)$ the third derivative or the function cubed? Usually if its a derivative that number is in parenthesis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inequality is
$$f (f (x))>f (1-5x) $$

$$\iff f (x)<1-5x $$
since $f $ is decreasing at R.

$$\iff 1-x-x^3 <1-5x $$
$$\iff x (2-x)(2+x)<0$$

$\iff x>0$ and $(2-x)(2+x)<0$

or

$x <0$ and $ (2-x)(2+x)>0$

$$\iff x\in (2,+\infty)\cup (-2,0) $$

Answer (score 2):

LHS is a function of $f$. To make it more clear, let $y=f(x)$, then 
$$ LHS = 1 - y - y^3 = f(y) = f(f(x)).$$
You have shown that $f$ is decreasing, so the original inequality becomes
$$ f(x) < 1 - 5x ,$$
i.e.,
\begin{align*}
& 1 - x - x^3 <  1 - 5x \\
\Rightarrow & x(x+2)(x-2) > 0.
\end{align*}
Solving this inequality produces the answer in your book. Here is a plot:
[image: Here is a plot]